# Excel.Workbook as a Global variable C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am trying to read and write to several excel sheets and I have split the functions into different methods.

The problem I am encountering is I cannot carry over the Workbook/Worksheet names over into the second method.

First method: Open all the relevant excel documents i.e Parts list, Export list etc.

Second method: Copy data from Parts List to first sheet in Export list.

For example in the first method I may have

```cs
//Ws = Worksheet
//Wb = Workbook 
//Workbooks and applications already defined

var PartsExportWs = PartsExportWb.Sheets[1].Name;
```

In the Second method I have:

```cs
public static void Parts
{
    int PartsCounterX;
    int TypicalCounterY = 4;
    int NullCounter = 0;

    var ConCatPartsCellValue = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

    for (PartsCounterX = 1; NullCounter <= 3; ++PartsCounterX)
    {
        var PartsCellValue = PartsExportWs.Cells[TypicalCounterY, PartsCounterX].Value;
        // etc ...
```

However, it errors out at PartsExportWs with the Description of "The name PartsExportWs does not exist in the current context"

I may be wrong but I am assuming that it is due to the fact it is not classed as a Global variable.

(If anyone has any suggestions it would be more than helpful. Even if it is on how to ask the question better!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access a local variable from one method in the code from another method.

You either need to [pass the variable as a parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-parameters), or [store it in a field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields).

*(There is no such thing as a "global variable" in C#.)*